# Do patent drawing lines need to be fully connected?

Tags: patent-drawings

I'm using Autodesk Inventor, and the perspective drawings look great. However, upon closer inspection, some lines aren't perfectly touching, likely because the part curves and a solid line would be faux.

How picky is the patent office? When zoomed out and printed, this is barely perceptible. My school hand-drafting teacher would have a conniption fit. From experience, would the patent office prefer I try to fake these missing lines with free-drawing?

[image: Drawing lines do not completely touch]

Comment: I’d just clean things up manually. You’ll probably be adding annotations any ways.

Comment: Also, if Inventor is giving you gaps, you probably have problems with the actual model.

Comment: @EricS Will do, and thanks.

Comment: @EricS Yes, gaps make sense when a part cuts into another part. In this case the gaps are on curved/beveled parts that are all by themselves. I suspect the profile of the curves are not being fully drawn because they are not true edges.

Comment: @Drakes that should be indicated by diagonal lines even if this may work for everyday purposes to convey the idea. Also do mean literally free hand drawing, why would you not use a function that extends the actual curve?

Comment: @PatentosPite About extending the curve, here is some background: in Inventor, I can model the disclosure to the point I can 3D print it. Now, I use the Drawing feature which takes a real digital model at a chosen perspective and makes it into a line-art figure which I can then annotate (as illustrated in my question). This is not an editable sketch, so unless I’m not aware of such a great feature, I can’t run a kind of “extend line” operation like I could do in a part sketch. Is that what you meant?

Comment: On above advice, I am overlaying a sketch on top of the line-art figure in Drawing mode to connect those lines. Fun fact, I’m also unable to figure out if Inventor can add line shadings; so far it can add real shadings and textures to Drawings, but not those drafting-board hand shadings of straight-line segments we did in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it represents your indented drawing close enough that if you get a notice to fix it you can just fix it.

These are the [USPTO drawings rules](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1606.html) for national applications. The [drawing rules for PCT applications](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1825.html) are more strict.

A popular book is [How to Make Patent Drawings: Save Thousands of Dollars and Do It With a Camera and Computer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1413326331)

A more straightforward patent drawing book

[How to Make Patent Drawings: A Patent It Yourself Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1413312578)

Comment: this is funny, I think this is exactly what I used to be doing unaware of this book — I presume the idea is that one takes a photo, convert it to black & white, increase contrast than generates a vector graphic drawing from which some minimal touch-ups and one has demonstrative drawings, or _figures_.

Comment: “artistically and competently executed” - I’m going to ready that gem of a phrase next time I need to give polite feedback.